# My submenu with jQuery is sliding down and up, when mouse already leaves, many times as I did repeatedly

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with submenus, and I develloped a simple jQuery script to show and hide my submenus.

But Im having a problem when I pass above menu item with submenus repeatedly and then I leave that menu item, I see my submenu siding down and up many times as I did in my repeatedly mouse movement.

Do you know how I can fix this?

This is my script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu .li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown("fast");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

And here I have my menu structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="li"><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="li"><a href="#">Products</a>
           <ul class="submenu">
               <li><a  href="#">Add</a></li>
               <li><a  href="">Remove</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle illustrating your problem? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: when i tried this out in a JSfiddle i noticed that the UL's bullet-point symbol also triggers the animation, but the space between the bullet point and the text of the UL does not trigger the animation. That's funny. Do you have css removing the bullet point symbol?     list-style-type: none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.stop()` function to cancel any animations that are currently running and/or queued:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu .li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.submenu').stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.submenu').stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G39QK/

Comment: Thank you JustcallmeDrago, I didnt know that. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: JustcallmeDrago, after all, its not working correct! I dont have my question problem but Im having other, I just can slidedown my menu item with submenus sometimes. In most cases, I cant slidedown into my submenu. Do you see why this can be happening?

Comment: If I solved the problem in your original question, you can accept my answer and post another question (and link me to it, if you don't mind). If it is not solved, would you provide a jsfiddle and explain in detail what is going on?

Comment: JustCallmeDrago, sorry, I forgot to accept, I already accepted but I got 10minutes error and then I forgot that I didnt accept yet. Really sorry!

Comment: JustCallmeDrago I update this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G39QK/1/. Its not the same in terms of design like I want but the problem Im having is like what Im having in this jsfiddle. When I hover "Products" and I slidedown I get some kind of conflict and I cant slide to my submenus items.

Comment: Do you see that kind of conflict in my fiddle?

Comment: Yes I do, it has to do with the fact that the gap between the menu and the submenu isn't part of the menu element. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: This is purely a css issue. Do two things: add `position: relative` to  `.li` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position - *The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor*) and set `top` from `69px` to `100%` (puts the top at the bottom of the menu button). That way, it is positioned correctly with no gap between the menu and submenu.

Comment: Thank you really. It was really that css issue! Now it is really working perfeclty!